# -su: /dev/tty: No such device or address

Tags: linux, docker, terminal, debian, tty

could please someone explain to me why this happens?

```
# su - someone -s /bin/bash -c "ls -la /dev/tty"
crw-rw-rw- 1 nobody nogroup 5, 0 Dec  7 20:53 /dev/tty
# BUT:
# su - someone -s /bin/bash -c "echo hello > /dev/tty"
-su: /dev/tty: No such device or address
```

I'm trieng to build a docker Container which has two services inside. Those services a startet by a Shell-Script:

```
CMD ["./starter.sh"]
```

Withing the `Dockerfile` I have redirected the Logs to `/dev/stderr` or `/dev/tty`

```
# None of the following works:
RUN ln -sf /dev/tty /var/log/thelog.log
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/thelog.log
RUN ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/thelog.log
```

The problem is that I'm trying to run one of the services as not root (`su -
 someone -c "service"`), which give's the following error:

```
unable to open log file [/var/log/thelog.log]: [6] No such device or address
```

How could I solve this problem? I want the logs to be linked to `/dev/*` AND want to run the User as non-root. Also I tried to add the User to the group `tty`, which did not work out.

Thanks.

Comment: Replacing devices with symlinks seems like a very brittle and dangerous thing to do. The kernel manipulates the tty, it's not a static file descriptor, that's why you get the error in the first place.

Comment: Wrap the service in something which captures its output to a sensible place. Most sane services don't really print anything to the console anyway.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but doing so is a common practice with docker. Redirecting to `/dev/*` makes you see the logs with `docker logs mycontainer`. So the crux of this matter is the `su - ` and starting the process as another (!=root) user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manpage for **su** states that *the executed command will have no controlling terminal*.  Any writes to /dev/tty will return the ENXIO error:

```
$ errno ENXIO
ENXIO 6 No such device or address
```

**sudo** does allocate a controlling terminal:

```
sudo -u someone /bin/bash -c "echo hello > /dev/tty"
```

There's no need for you to make a symbolic link to /dev/tty (/dev/stdout and /dev/stderr is enough) or use **sudo** if you use the **USER** directive in the Dockerfile or [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).

Comment: Hi thanks. Yes, true I could use supervisor and I know about `USER`. But how do you start 2 services with a Shell-Script where one must run as non root and one as root without using supervisor? If I use `USER non_root` I could not start the root-service as I have only one `RUN` command.

Comment: Either use supervisor or run each service in a different container.

Comment: Just wanted to complement, that even with `supervisord` it is not possible to use `/dev/tty` as a non-root User.